# How can I insert commas in number strings to separate the zeros?

Tags: java, string, number-formatting

```
public class test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String abra = "100000";
        abra = abra.replace(abra.substring(abra.length() - 3),
               "," + abra.substring(abra.length() - 3));
        System.out.println(abra);
     }
}
```

Totally new to java and i'm trying to replace a number with comma to separate the zeros by three. It works fine for thousands and ten thousands, but i'm getting wierd results for more. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use [`NumberFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html).

Comment: Thanks alot, now please upvote this post. I've edited the questions such that it better describes the problem!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you're manually only for 6 digits. A better approach will be using [`NumberFormat#getNumberInstance`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html#getNumberInstance-java.util.Locale-) with [`Locale.US`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html#US):

> A Locale object represents a specific geographical, political, or
>   cultural region. An operation that requires a Locale to perform its
>   task is called locale-sensitive and uses the Locale to tailor
>   information for the user. For example, displaying a number is a
>   locale-sensitive operation— the number should be formatted according
>   to the customs and conventions of the user's native country, region,
>   or culture.

---

```
NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.US).format(20000000);
// 20,000,000
```